# How to keep Windows focussing just on one task

Tags: windows, tasks, workflow

I many times leave computer running overnight to create proxies for video editing.

Is there any way how to let windows use all computing power just for one application ?

Thank you

Comment: Most likely not. The program must be capable of using multiple treads. If that is not the case, its going to be impossible. If so, you can set its priority to very high and it should maximize its performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows is not the best for letting you control how the computer uses its resources, but...

In Task Manager's Details tab, right click an entry and select Priority, then set to real time to allocate maximum priority to your desired task.  This will not really do what you want because Windows, but the closest you can get.

To find the task details you want:
From Task Manager Processes, right click and select Go to details.
Easily find details entry in Task Manager[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39M1F.png)

Then in Details view, right click entry - Set priority - Realtime[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqYPc.png)

Comment: You should add that if the application is a single core process, it will maximize one core at most. On a 4 core processor, the cpu will hit 25% at best.